# Material Design for Angular 2 documentation for version 2.0.0-beta.7

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular and material design. Came from iOS Development and this one is hard for me. I have project in my company and I'm looking for documentation for Material Design version 2.0.0-beta.7 for Angular. I know there is nice site [here](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) with documentation of each component but  I noticed that this is for version 2.0.0-beta.12 and for example all prefixes Md was changed to Mat. I tried to update Md to version 2.0.0-beta.12 but then I have issues like this in my project:

```
npm WARN @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~4.4.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/common@~4.4.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/core@~4.4.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12 requires a peer of @angular/common@~4.4.4 but none was installed.
```

In this moment I stopped because I'm afraid since I don't have enough experience with this kind of problems in angular world and I fell that I'm missing something. I don't want to update all @angular/core etc because in current project everything is running ok. We just need to add more component using Material Design and since I'm learning it I need documentation for my version because beta.12 is very different as I noticed. So I get back to version beta.7 so the project is running again but hey. Where is the docs for this version? How to find it?

Here is my package.json deps and devDeps:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.3",
    "ag-grid": "^13.3.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^13.3.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "6.0.78",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.6",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
```

Comment: As the other comments mention, you should really push through and try to get it updated to beta.12. Upgrading from @angular/* 4.2.4 to 4.4.4 will not cause any breaking changes, but you must look through the Material changelog. If you are determined not to upgrade, you can look through the [source here](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/2.0.0-beta.7) and look at the READMEs for each component and the examples.

Comment: Thank You. I updated core to 4.4.5 and the project works. Then I updated material and I was forced to change a lot in code. Prefixes from Md to Mat etc but hey it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

since Angular Material 2 version beta 11, the library now requires Angular 4.4.3 or greater so you should update to the latest version of angular to resolve the issue. Here is a good website that lets you select the version you are currently using and to which version you want to upgrade and gives you all the required steps:

---

[**Angular Update Guide**](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/)

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link. I followed this tool but now I know I shouldnt touch typescript because last version is generating a lot of errors in other dependencies. Also compiler-cli and typescript should be in devDependencies. This tool should get package.json on the input and should work based on this to generate needed steps. But thanks for the info about this tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer to your package.json you will see that you must update your @angular/core from 4.2.3 to ~4.4.4. The same applies for @angular/common

Try this

**On Linux/Mac:**

`npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save`

**On Windows:**
`npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save`

Comment: Should @angular/compiler-cli be in dependencies or devDependencies? The same question to typescript? After updating typescript but in devDependencies I have a lot of errors.